# Existe la relacion entre producto y subcategoria?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo con Laravel una pagina de una libreria y tengo que crear 3 tablas en la BD(MYSQL).
Las 3 tablas son: categorias, subcategorias y productos.
Lo que quiero hacer es agregar 3 subcategorias a las 2 categorias principales que son Literatura y Papeleria.
Tengo pensado hacer una tabla de subcategorías y relacionarla a la tabla categorías.
Pero mi duda es si existe también la relación entre producto y subcategoria.

Abajo dejo modelos y migraciones de cada tabla.

**Modelo de Producto:**

```
class Producto extends Model {
    public $table = "productos";
    public $primaryKey = "id";
    //public $timestamps
    public $guarded = [];

    public function categorias() {
     return $this->belongsTo("App\Categoria", "categoria_id");
 }


public function subcategorias() {
  return $this->belongsTo("App\Subcategorias", "subcategoria_id");
}
```

**Producto Migracion:**

```
public function up() {
        Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('imagen');
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->integer('precio');
            $table->foreignId('categoria_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('subcategoria_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Modelo de Categoria:**

```
class Categoria extends Model {
    public $table = "categorias";
    public $primaryKey = "id";
    //public $timestamps = "";
   public $guarded = [];

   public function productos() {
         return $this->hasMany("App\Producto", "categoria_id");
   }
  public function subcategorias() {
   return $this->belongsTo("App\Subcategorias", "subcategoria_id");
}
```

**Categoria Migracion:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->foreignId('subcategoria_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Modelo de Subcategoria:**

```
class Subcategorias extends Model{
  public $table = "subcategorias";
  public $primaryKey = "id";
  //public $timestamps = "";
 public $guarded = [];

 public function categorias() {
       return $this->belongsTo("App\Categoria", "categoria_id");
 }
 public function productos() {
       return $this->hasMany("App\Producto", "subcategoria_id");
 }
}
```

**Subcategoria Migracion:**

```
Schema::create('subcategorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('imagen');
        $table->string('descripcion');
 $table->foreignId('categoria_id')->constrained();
        $table->timestamps();
      });
```

Comment: La duda en si no es de Laravel si no de cómo interpretas las reglas de negocio para componer tu base de datos, además que luce basada en opiniones y eso generaría su cierre, checa [ask]

Comment: @BetaM Bueno, ya agregue codigo para ser mas especifica. Gracias!

Comment: un producto no puede tener una subcategoria por si sola, siempre depende de una categoria... lo que si, el producto sabra su categoria y la subcategoria dentro de este...

Comment: igual el problema no es de laravel si no de diseño de base de datos..

Comment: @gbianchi ya se, por eso deje los modelos y migraciones